# Are developer messages useful?

Tags: dark-souls-3

I've found out on wiki that Seek Guidance miracle allows player to see hidden messages from developers.

Are these messages helpful? Do they contain any lore info? Where can I find them?
Is there complete list of them somewhere?

I've found out list of such for DS1 on [fextralife wiki](http://darksouls.wiki.fextralife.com/Seek+Guidance): do DS3 examples look similar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are useful as they give tips for the various secrets. A [list is found on wikidot](http://darksouls3.wikidot.com/seek-guidance), though I don't know if it's complete. They don't really contain any lore and most of them are not really needed anymore as the various player messages, bloodstains and phantoms easily show you what the messages are hinting at.